# Using PHP variable in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save HTML code into MySQL database. There is no problem when I save it, but I have a field that I want to put a value into it.

```
<input type="text" size="18" value="$user" />
```

When I retrieve it from the database and send it to the browser, the value of the text field is not the value of `$user` variable.

Here is my php code to save:

```
function SaveHTML(){
    global $cn;
    $content=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["html"],$cn);
    $url=mysql_real_escape_string("http://www.google.com/",$cn);
    mysql_query("Insert into HTML(content,URL) values('$content','$url')");
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` by concatenating SQL code with data read from the network. That is a hotbed for SQL injections. Use `prepare` instead: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You should use prepared statements (PHP PDO) instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. EDIT: dang, got me by 29 seconds, I'll leave the PDO link up for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to echo the value to display it:

```
<input type="text" size="18" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
```

As you can see I also used [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent against [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Also please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for *new* code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Another thing I notice is that you are using the `global` keyword. It would be better to inject the connection as a parameter in the function:

```
function SaveHTML($cn){
    $content=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["html"],$cn);
    $url=mysql_real_escape_string("http://www.google.com/",$cn);
    mysql_query("Insert into HTML(content,URL) values('$content','$url')");
}
```

Edit (Death):

What I wanted is the folllowing:

Assume you have a varivle `$user`  and piece of  HTML code like below:

```
$html = <<<'Death'
<input type="text" size="18" value="$user" />
Death;
```

now, If I save this variable (`$html`) to a database and in another page I send this html to user, what should I do to the `$user` in html code have value of `$user` in second page?

Answer:
I saved string (as it is) to database and then used `eval()` function to replace the `$user` with it's value!

**EDIT PeeHaa**

Note that in *most* cases it is considered bad practice to have HTML in your database (unless you). I'm also not that happy about with `eval()` stuff (which is always bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

you can use personal tags and after reading from database replace that tag with php variable
like this :

```
$html = '<input type="text" class="class" value="{user}">';
save $html to database  
$gethtml = get $html from database ; 

$last_html = str_replace('{user}',$user,$gethtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that it's PHP code.

```
<input type="text" size="18" value="<?php echo $user ?>" />
```

Comment: You'd also have to `eval()` the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the value of the input, first you need to give it a name:

```
<input name="user" type="text" value="<?php echo $user?>" />
```

now to retrieve it and save it in your db you have to get it from the POST variable

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
```

this will get you the value that you need.